# Github Pages doesnt check folders

Tags: github

i have https://github.com/angerminecraftyt/serverlistunreach but the CSS isnt loading

there is a X in the file as it wasnt checked by Github Pages

Now if u go to https://unreachhost.ml the css didnt load
How to fix this?

Comment: Use `../` in front of the file path

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577).